# Finding specific names in a random list

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched through many different questions and answers and can't quite find what I am looking for.
I have a sheet of data with a long list of names in column E and a value in column F that corresponds with the name. What I want to do is search through this long list for specific names to then return the corresponding value and copy it to another sheet.

My problem is that the list of names and order of the names does change depending on the testing completed but my search criteria will always be the same, up to 150 names to search.

Many thanks in advance and sorry if this has been posted before

Comment: Searching is fine but did you try anything? Record a macro perhaps? You need to show us what do you understand on how the code logic should work... and what have you tried and finally where are you stuck :)

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` should work for this

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
Private Sub findAndCopy()
Dim names As Range
Dim nameToFind As String
Dim sheetName As Worksheet
Dim cellToCopyInto As Range

'Set these to your actual values
nameToFind = "John"
Set sheetName = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set cellToCopyInto = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A1")

Set names = Range("E1:E150").Find(nameToFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)

cellToCopyInto.Value = names.Offset(0, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!